# Android Studio EGL Bad match error?

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I had my app working fine, then worked with the colors in this xml file and now this error pops up, I will post xml file code with error info under it. HOW DO I FIX THIS?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Signup!"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#f17a0a"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="State"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="City"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:hint="Retype"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
         />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText6"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"

        android:background="#00FFFF" />

    <Button
        android:text="Sign Me Up!!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:textColor="#f17a0a"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:hint="Address 2"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:background="#7A0019"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="Zipcode"
        android:textColor="#00FF00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:id="@+id/textView12" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the error

> E/EGL_emulation: tid 2805: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0x942c4ba0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.ratcl032.updatedtshirtstoreryan, PID: 2499
>                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class EditText
>                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class EditText
>                     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find
>   ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x1080295
>                         at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:840)
>                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:998)
>                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:531)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1076)
>                         at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:64)
>                         at android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
>                         at com.example.ratcl032.updatedtshirtstoreryan.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:19)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Are you running your app on emulator ?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing from hardware to software like a few forums said but the same thing happened

Answer (score 0):

The EGL error is an implication of the real issue:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML
>   file line #28: Error inflating class EditText Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error
>   inflating class EditText Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find
>   ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x1080295 at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:840)
>   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:998)
>   at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:531)
>   at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1076) at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:64) at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:60) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>   at...

In one of your layout-files, you use an EditText with a drawable, using/being a color state list.

The drawable has the ID 0x1080295. In the R.java-file (generated), search for the number and check which is the identifier of the assigned variable.
Use this identifier to find the problematic EditText.

It might help to manually delete the generated folder, clean, (possibly make) and rebuild completely.

Comment: is there a way I could just delete this value in my XML thay I copy pasted on here?

Comment: I cannot know, what "@+id/..." the above number is mapped to. Sure, if the mapped id is contained in the XML file, you could delete the id-property. But is this what you want?